# Determine Alphabetic Order of Two Characters in Java

Tags: java

Is there a better way to do this?

```
/* Compares two characters.  
   If ch1 is alphabetically smaller than ch2, return true
   If ch1 is equal to ch2 or is alphabetically greater, return false
*/
public static boolean smallestCharacter(char ch1, char ch2) {
    return Character.parseChar((new String(ch1)).toLowerCase()) < 
                 Character.parseChar((new String(ch2)).toLowerCase())
}
```

Update: It can be assumed that ch1, and ch2 are both characters from the english alphabet. If you have a similar question, but can't assume that ch2 and ch2 are English characters, I suggest reading @Tedd Hopp's Answer.

Comment: What do you mean by alphabetical order? Which alphabet? What if a user provides a character that isn't part of that alphabet?

Comment: @Mark et al, based on the code, it means case should be ignored, i.e. `B < c` _and_ `b < C`.

Comment: @Mark those are quite valid concerns. The purpose of this question was to find a less obtuse way to compare two characters from the english alphabet, while ignoring case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

what about

```
return Character.toLowerCase(ch1) < Character.toLowerCase(ch2);
```

Comment: This will work provided the Unicode code points for the two characters corresponds to OP's notion of "alphabetic order". It's fine for English, but not for many other languages. For more general settings, it's necessary, I think, to use a [Collator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) with the proper locale.

Comment: Also this won't work for _supplementary characters_ to be exact.

Comment: Ted Hopp is right. Unless you're limiting yourself to only ASCII characters, it's way more complicated than that. For example, the letter Ą is 0104 in Unicode, which means that a naive sorting function would put it after Z (005A). Which is nonsense - every Polish schoolchild knows that Ą comes right after A.

Comment: @TedHopp You could write that up with some more detail as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

For English (and many other languages), you can just use Character.toLowerCase as @aleph_null proposes. This compares characters based on their (lower case) Unicode code points. For some languages, however, this will be wrong. (For instance, in German, ß — eszett — comes between 's' and 't'. However, its Unicode value is U+00DF, which would make it come after 'z'.)

The only way comparing two characters makes sense is with reference to a locale. One way to do this is to use a Collator:

```
/**
 * Compares two characters, ignoring all but primary differences. (Case
 * is a tertiary difference.)
 * @return true if ch1 is alphabetically smaller than ch2; false otherwise
 */
public static boolean smallestCharacter(char ch1, char ch2, Locale locale) {
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(locale);
    collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY); // Collator.SECONDARY would work
    return 0 > collator.compare(Character.toString(ch1),
                                Character.toString(ch2)
                               );
}
```

(P.S., `new String(ch1)` is not the way to create a String object containing a given char value.)

Answer (score 3):

Don't create String object for each character.
You can use simple `Character.toLowerCase(char)`
After that your comparison method is:

```
public boolean smallestCharacter(char a, char b){
    return Character.toLowerCase(a) < Character.toLowerCase(b)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
public static boolean smallestCharacter(char ch1, char ch2) {
  if (ch1 > 0x60) ch1 -= 0x20;
  if (ch2 > 0x60) ch2 -= 0x20;
  return ch1 < ch2;
}
```